# Service client with Mutual Authentication (2-way client certificate authentication)

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I'm trying to create a connection to a web service through their WSDL.  I was told the service's authentication is described as TLS with authentication by exchanging certificates.  I generated the client via the "Add Service Reference" in visual studio.  When I send a command, I expect to see the "handshake" in wire shark but I do not even see the "Client Hello" initiation being sent.

The service's authentication is described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Description

My client is writen in c#

Here is the full program I am running to test the connection(it starts with Run()):

```
public class ClientExample
{
    private const string Url =
        "https://xxxxxxxxx";

    public static void Run()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateCertificate;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        PerformTest("Clear Cache", GetBinding());
    }

    private static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var bec = new BindingElementCollection
            {
                new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8),
                new HttpsTransportBindingElement{ RequireClientCertificate = true }
            };
        return new CustomBinding(bec);
    }

    private static void PerformTest(string test, Binding binding)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ResetColor();

            var client = GetClient(binding);
            SendMessage(client);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DisplayError(e);
        }
    }

    private static MyClient GetClient(Binding binding)
    {
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(Url);

        var client = new MyClient(binding, endpointAddress);

        if (client.ClientCredentials != null)
        {
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
                                                                      X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                                                      "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");                
        }
        return client;
    }

    private static void SendMessage(ChargePointServiceClient client)
    {
        var response = client.clearCache("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", new ClearCacheRequest());
        Console.WriteLine(ClearCacheDescription(response));
    }

    private static string ClearCacheDescription(ClearCacheStatus response)
    {
        switch (response)
        {
            case ClearCacheStatus.Accepted:
                return "Accepted";
            case ClearCacheStatus.Rejected:
                return "Rejected";
        }

        return "Unkown";
    }

    private static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
        switch (sslpolicyerrors)
        {
            case SslPolicyErrors.None:
                return true;
            case SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors:
                DisplayWarningMessage("RemoteCertificateChainErrors");
                return false;
            case SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch:
                DisplayWarningMessage("RemoteCertificateNameMismatch");
                return false;
            case SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable:
                DisplayWarningMessage("RemoteCertificateNotAvailable");
                return false;
            default:
                DisplayWarningMessage("Unkown Certificate Validation Error");
                return false;
        }
    }

    private static void DisplayError(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null)
            return;

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(@"Exception");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);

        if (exception.InnerException != null)
            Console.WriteLine();

        DisplayError(exception.InnerException);
    }

    private static void DisplayWarningMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

I logged all network traffic via system.diagnostic in my app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Cache">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="System.Net"
      type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      traceOutputOptions="None"
      initializeData="network.log"
    />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**Here are some of the log lines of interest**:

This confirms that a tls stream is created:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] TlsStream#50727427::.ctor(host=xxxxx, #certs=1)
```

A secure channel is created:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819::.ctor(hostname=xxxxxxx, #clientCertificates=1, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     LiveSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819 - Attempting to restart the session using the user-provided certificate: [Version]
```

Not sure why a private key is being looked up:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819 - Left with 1 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819 - Trying to find a matching certificate in the certificate store.
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819 - Locating the private key for the certificate: [Version]
```

At this point in the log, I see that certificates are exchanged.  Unfortunately wire shark doesn't confirm this...

Now my program verifies the services certificate and starts processing

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] SecureChannel#11159819 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user.
System.Net Information: 0 : [9040] ProcessAuthentication(Protocol=Ssl3, Cipher=Rc4 128 bit strength, Hash=Sha1 160 bit strength, Key Exchange=RsaKeyX 2048 bit strength).
```

I then see some encrypted data exchanged and my clear cache command is sent

I receive an encrypted response from the service but the message indicates a Fault.  I assume this is because the authentication wasn't accepted by the service

```
System.Net Error: 0 : [9040] Exception in HttpWebRequest#46890055::GetResponse - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..
```

Here is the filter I am using in wireshark (both IPs are the service not mine)

```
(ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xx or ip.dst == xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) and ssl.handshake
```

Also, the certificate I am using does not have a private key.  I assume that I shouldn't need one from the TLS documentation.

So my question is why I do not see the Client Hello/Server Hello in wireshark when I run the program or how should I configure the client binding to initiate the client hello?

(I tagged wcf because I assume wcf professionals might know the answer to my question. My solution will be independent of wcf because I do not have control of the services bindings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is using client-side certificate authentication in SSL/TLS. In that case, the client certificate you're using definitely needs to have a private key, which is necessary in order to complete the SSL/TLS handshake.

Notice that when configuring the client, you need to tell the binding to use client certificates for transport authentication:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
```

And then tell it how to locate the certificate you want to use using the ClientCertificate behavior:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="CN=clienttempcert" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
          storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Notice that the certificate you specify key *MUST HAVE* a private key that the client can load (the service, however, does not need the private key at all).

Comment: This is the part I am unclear about.  I was told to download the certificate through the browser and the certificate I downloaded doesn't have a private key.  When I open the certificate it says "This certificate is intended for the following purpose(s): * Endure the identity of a remote computer.  * Proves your identity to a remote computer."  To me, it seems that I simply provide the certificate to the service to prove identity, then the encryption happens via step 4 described in the wiki link I provided.

Comment: I assume a browser would have the same mechanism when visiting an https site.  The browser wouldn't have the private key but the communication eventually become encrypted.

Comment: Where are you downloading the certificate from? Is this from a Certificate Authority? Normally, if you're generating a new certificate with a certificate authority, the CA doesn't get or generate the private key, that's only generated on the machine where the request is made, and then the key is matched to the certificate when you download it back into the same machine.

Comment: I'm using firefox to visit the site I'm trying to communicate with (https).  If you click on the padlock you can view the certificate and export it.  I'm not getting it from a CA or performing a CSR.  When I was told this is how I should get the certificate I was a little baffled.  This would be so much easier with a .pfx file that has a private key...

Comment: You are talking about the server certificate, but you said the site/service requires a *client* side certificate. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: You are right.  The instructions I was given told me to download their certificate but it turns out that the instructions where not specified for my case.  I did in fact need to supply my own certificate, with its own private key, to identify myself.  After I worked this out with my them, I was able to send my message.

Comment: It's strange though, I never saw the traffic using wire shark but I'm not concerned since I can successfully send messages.  Anyway, I'll mark this as the correct answer even though the security mode isn't what I am using since I am using customBinding.  Thanks for the help tomasr.

Comment: @aelstonjones : I also need to do something like this. So please tell whether your private key was marked exportable or not.

Answer (score 1):

Get the PFX, and install it to the server certs. to personal store or currentstore, local machine store etc.

and then use this in the asp.net web.config and use findbyThumbPrint.

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="yourthumprinthere" storeLocation="CurrentUser" or PersonalStore
          storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```